# Request method 'POST' not supported Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

Basically, I have a HTML search form which allows me to search within the database. A JavaScript function is called when the form is submitted but I'm not redirected to the required page. 
"Request method 'POST' not supported" is the error message received.

My code:

```html
<form th:object="${devices}" method="POST" onsubmit="return fireAction()">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

```js
function fireAction() {
    var searchInput = document.getElementById('search').value;
    var searchFilter = document.getElementById('deviceAttributes').value;
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('lastEntry').checked;

    alert(searchInput + " " + searchFilter + " " + checkbox);
    if (searchInput == "" || searchInput == null) {
        alert("Search field cannot be null.");
        return false;

    } else if (checkbox) {
        window.location.href = '/current/' + searchInput
                + '/filter/' + searchFilter;

    } else {
        window.location.href = '/showForm/' + searchInput
                + '/filter/' + searchFilter;
    }
}
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/showForm/{keyword}/filter/{searchFilter}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showForm(@PathVariable("keyword") String keyword,
@PathVariable("searchFilter") String searchFilter, Model model) {
    Devices devices = new Devices();
    devices.setSearch(keyword);
    devices.setSearchFilter(searchFilter);
    model.addAttribute(
    "addDevices",
    device.findByDevicesName(devices.getSearch(),
            devices.getSearchFilter()));
    return "showForm";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/current/{keyword}/filter/{searchFilter}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String currentDevices(@PathVariable("keyword") String keyword,
@PathVariable("searchFilter") String searchFilter, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("devices", new Devices());
    Devices devices = new Devices();
    devices.setSearch(keyword);
    devices.setSearchFilter(searchFilter);
    List<Devices> newList = device.allDevices();
    ListIterator<Devices> iterator = newList.listIterator();
    List<Devices> resultList = new ArrayList<Devices>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Devices device = iterator.next();
        if (searchLastEntry(device, keyword, searchFilter)) {
         resultList.add(device);
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("iterator2", resultList);
    return "current";
}
```

Comment: What's the URL you see in your browser's network traffic tab?

Comment: @kryger
GET http://localhost:8080/showForm/ss/filter/deviceName 
POST http://localhost:8080/

Comment: `window.location.href` issues a GET so it's not clear why you expected this to be a POST. That's a fairly contrived and non-orthodox way to submit a form, either way.

Comment: If you want to change navigation to a new page use a link instead of submitting a form; change controllers' `@RequestMethod` from POST to GET.

Comment: I have tried that but still not working. I'm redirected to an URL 
http://localhost:8080/?search=ACCELERA&_uidNumber=on&_uidNumber=on&_uidNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a return false in your javascript after executing the `window.location.href` - So i suspect that after the javascript executes the asynchronous GET request to window.location.href, then the function ends and control is passed back to the form, which just does the normal POST action, but you haven't defined an action URL (which explains the GET then POST requests you say you have seen in the network tab).

Aside, as mentioned in the comments, you probably shouldn't be using POST for a search form - Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp